# update plotly hoverTemplate's in scatterplot's customData with variable instead of hardcoding a number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

```
bollSpreadCol = dfIbFour.columns.get_loc("bollSpread")
sma = go.Scatter(x=dfIbFour.index, y=dfIbFour["sma"], name="SMA", line=dict(color="blue", dash="dot", width = 4),customdata=dfIbFour,
                        hovertemplate="Date:%{customdata[0]}<br>"+ \
                                        "**BollSpr: %{customdata[10]:.2f} | LowBollCum%: %{customdata[34]:.2%} | SMACum%: %{customdata[36]:.2%} | EMACum%: %{customdata[39]:.2%}<br> "
                                        )
```

I was wondering how would able to get the variable I created called **bollSpreadCol, which is currently at 11** into a plotly Scatter()

In particular, i'm trying to replace the **10 in BollSpr: %{customdata[10]:.2f}** with **bollSpreadCol**

I'm looking to have a variable that will have the correct column number of **"bollSpread"** for whenever I add new data types to my current dataFrame.  It's becoming very cumbersome that I have to manually enter the column everytime I make a change.  I'm not too sure how to properly include the variable in the plotly template?  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may not understand all of your data. To lessen the burden of manually modifying column names, since the hover template is composed of strings, it is easier to use a column number list and string concatenation for the target column. From the data example in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/), answer the code to set any column name and custom data column number.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['Date'],
    y=df["AAPL.Adjusted"],
    name="Adjust",
    line=dict(color="blue", dash="dot", width = 4),
    customdata=df,
))

col_list = [0,6,7,8,9]
new_template = ""
for col in col_list:
    new_template = new_template + df.columns[col]+":"+f"%{{customdata[{col}]}}<br>"
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=new_template)
#print(new_template)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much r-beginners for your solution!  I was easily able to adjust what you provided to include bollSpreadCol into the code.  Greatly appreciated!!!!